# Magento2 : Display maps on another page by clicking link of one phtml page

Tags: magento2, link

- i want a map link on my home.phtml page (view map) .
- which will redirect to other phtml page to display that map.
- On home.phtml there are multiple view map available like(view map delhi,view map  america etc) i want all of them to redirect on that page
- simply i want to fetch different maps for different link?

Comment: questing is confusing , refine your question in points

Comment: You have different maps on a CMS page , and you want to open that page when user click on any "view map" link on home page ?

Comment: yes i have iframe link of google maps for different places

Comment: You want to open iframe link or CMS page link ?

Comment: on home page there is a cms link which will redirect & on that cms page i want to fetch map through iframe link for that particular link

Comment: So what's problem , this should be simple putting links on home page and on CMS page put your i frame code .  Post your problem as well if any error coming in way

Comment: i don't want to open all the iframes at same time.  & how should i redirect on phtml page to other phtml page

Comment: all frames are on same page or different page ?

Comment: all iframes on same page one at a time.  otherwise i have to create so many pages

Comment: And when a user click on a link from home page then it should open the single map not all other maps on that page , right ?

Comment: yeah i think you got the point

Comment: are you using bootstrap , then this can be simpll done via accordion feature .... or you can place iiframes in different DIV and then assign an ID to it . So basically when that ID is triggered then CSS should change from display NONE to BLOCK

Comment: ok but how should  i redirect to other cms page .

Comment: Pass the URL of that page with DIV ID to that link and that will open the page automatically with specific DIV only , just need little CSS tweaking